# ¿Cómo excluir resultados de un query con mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas de la base de datos `usuario` y `network` en Mysql. Donde `network` es una tabla pivote para relacionar dos usuarios entre sí.

La entidad de usuario contiene información como id, nombre, password, etc.

La entidad network contiene dos id de usuarios: `origen` y `amigo`.

Necesito hacer un query para buscar usuarios por nombre o correo electrónico, pero excluyendo de la búsqueda los usuarios que se tengan agregados entre sí. Es decir, si el usuario con el id `93` tiene que excluir de la búsqueda los usuarios que ya tenga agregados en la tabla de network.

Si en mi tabla network tengo la siguiente información para el usuario `93`:

```
+--------+-------+
| origen | amigo |
+--------+-------+
|     82 |    93 |
|     83 |    93 |
|     90 |    93 |
|     93 |   178 |
|     93 |   208 |
|     93 |   209 |
|    210 |    93 |
+--------+-------+
```

¿De qué manera puedo modificar mi query para excluir de la búsqueda los usuarios que están relacionados con el id `93` a través de la tabla de network? Ejemplo: El usuario con id `93` hace la búsqueda con `roberto`. Donde `${texto}` representa la cadena texto a buscar.

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.nombre,
  u.apellido
FROM usuario as u
WHERE
  CONCAT(u.nombre, ' ', u.app) LIKE '%${texto}%'
  OR u.email LIKE '${texto}%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en este caso, ayuda un poco expresar el problema en lenguaje natural. Yo diría que estás buscando a todos los usuarios que no sean amigos de un usuario particular. Yendo un poco a lo técnico, agregaría que un usuario es *amigo* de otro cuando existe un registro en la tabla `network` que los relaciona, sin importar quien aparece en el campo `origen` y quién aparece en el campo `amigo`.

En otras palabras, los *amigos* de un usuario es la unión de los *origenes* cuando el *amigo* es el usuario de mi interés, con los *amigos* cuando el *origen* es usuario de mi interés, dicho en SQL:

```
select amigo from network where origen = 93
union 
select origen from network where amigo = 93
```

Luego, para encontrar todos los usuarios que no son amigos de `93`, podemos valernos de la operación `not in` y la consulta sería algo como:

```
select *
  from usuario
 where id != 93
   and id not in (select amigo from network where origen = 93
                  union 
                  select origen from network where amigo = 93
                 )
```

He excluido al propio usuario, pues en este caso, supongo que el usuario tampoco puede ser su propio amigo (asumiendo que la búsqueda es para mostrar los candidatos a poder ser amigos de alguien).

Comment: @Sergio siento decirte que esta es la unica respuesta que arregla la situacion del usuario. Tanto tu respuesta, como la que decis que esta copiada, sufren el mismo problema, y es que solo miran una mitad de la tabla network para comprobar al usuario. Usar un left join esta mal, porque te falta comparar contra la otra columna de la tabla network.

Answer (score 1):

Pudieras utilizar `NOT IN`, para negar todos los registros que coincidan con el campo network.amigo a través de una subconsulta y después agregar un `AND` en las comparaciones de texto que tienes:

```
SELECT
u.id,
u.nombre,
u.apellido
FROM usuario u
WHERE
  u.id NOT IN (SELECT n.amigo 
               FROM   network n 
               WHERE  n.origen = u.id
              )
AND (
        CONCAT(u.nombre, ' ', u.app) LIKE '%${texto}%'
        OR u.email LIKE '${texto}%'
    )
```